# Conditional Formatting Not Applying To All Cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight cells B3:D9 if the difference between D8 & D9 is more than or equal to 10,000.

I set up a true/false formula rule `=ABS($D8-$D9) >=10000` that applies to cells `=$B$3:$D$9`. When it's true, the range of cells should be highlighted and when it's false, it should go back to normal.

The problem is that only cells B3:D4 and cells B7:D9 are affected - B5:D6 sees no change when the formula is true.

Another problem is that when the formula is false, the formatting doesn't go away.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If the Applies to: range is `=$B$3:$D$9` then the formula needs to either `=ABS($D$8-$D$9) >=10000` for the whole block or `=ABS($D3-$D4) >=10000` or maybe `=ABS($D3-$D$9) >=10000` for individual rows. What is it **exactly** that you are trying to do? Your narrative is full of ambiguity.

Comment: @Jeeped I edited the question slightly- hope this helps

Comment: OK, the formula should be `=ABS($D$8-$D$9)>=10000`. You cannot leave the rows relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply conditional formatting to the whole block based on two cells you need to make the cell's row and references absolute, not just the columns.

Change the formula to:

```
=ABS($D$8-$D$9)>=10000
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for an hour before realizing why my condition only applied to the first column.
My reference range (French holiday dates) was on a separate sheet, and when selecting the range, I hit F4 as I usually do. BUT - you don't need to make the reference absolute, because it already is absolute...so when I hit F4 I made it relative...